# Boolean evaluation of a string without conditionals

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, boolean, substring

I'm trying to figure out the solution to this particular challenge and so far I'm stumped.

Basically, what I'm looking to do is:

1. Check if substring `false` exists in string `s`
2. If `false` exists in `s`, return the boolean `True`

However, I am not allowed to use any conditional statements **at all**.

Maybe there is a way to do this with objects?

Comment: What if `false` doesn't exist in `s`?

Comment: Then return blank

Comment: what do you consider "conditional statements" to be exactly?

Comment: Any kind of if statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is always `str.__contains__` if it's needed as a function somewhere:

```
In [69]: str.__contains__('**foo**', 'foo')
Out[69]: True
```

This could be used for things like `filter` or `map`:

```
sorted(some_list, key=partial(str.__contains__,'**foo**'))
```

The much more common usecase is to assign a truth value for each element in a list using a comprehension. Then we can make use of the `in` keyword in Python:

```
In[70]: ['foo' in x for x in ['**foo**','abc']]
Out[70]: [True, False]
```

The latter should always be preferred. There are edge cases where only a function might be possible.

But even then you could pass a lambda and use the statement:

```
sorted(some_list, key=lambda x: 'foo' in x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Evaluating condition without using if statement:

**True:**

```
>>> s = 'abcdefalse'
>>> 'false' in s
True
```

**False:**

```
>>> s = 'abcdefals'
>>> 'false' in s
False
```

**Return blank if False:**

```
>>> s = 'abcdefals'
>>> 'false' in s or ''
''
```

Comment: OP wants blank if False.

Comment: `'false' in s or None` (if 'blank' is `None`)

Comment: Also, your last method is what I suggested in my answer 13 minutes ago! ;)

Comment: Your input/output formatting is the wrong way around. I might be the only one bothered about this, but check out http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310839/should-i-prefix-example-python-code-with-to-indicate-running-in-the-interp :)

Comment: @SebastianWozny, thanks for your hint. I'll try to be more careful next time. ;-)

Comment: I like this answer a lot by the way. I upvoted, and I think it's the better answer. I just added the `__contains__` for completeness because sometimes you cant use a statement somewhere...

Comment: You edited your answer to contain my approach while my answer was still un-deleted. Then you edited my answer with a destructive edit so you could remove your upvote. I'm just letting you know, usually people don't appreciate that. Just like people usually don't appreciate others adopting their profile image as their own, though you're free to use it.